# Is there a better way to execute commands in JSON running python

Tags: python, json

Can somebody suggest a better way to execute multiple commands within JSON using Python.

For example how to improve the following:

JSON:

$ python -m json.tool test2.json

```
{
"command": "mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data2/opt/ODS",
"command1": "mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data4/opt/ODS",
"command2": "mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data5/opt/ODS"
}
```

Python:

```
$ cat parse.py
   import json
   import sys
   import subprocess
   from pprint import pprint

   jdata = open(sys.argv[1])

   data = json.load(jdata)

   print "start"
   print(data)
   subprocess.call(data['command'], shell=True)
   subprocess.call(data['command1'], shell=True)
   subprocess.call(data['command2'], shell=True)
   print "end"
   jdata.close()
```

Output:

]$ python parse.py test2.json
start
{u'command1': u'mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data4/opt/ODS', u'command2': u'mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data5/opt/ODS', u'command': u'mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data2/opt/ODS'}
end

TIA

Comment: Hi daimne, try using a json structure that is an array ( or list ) , not a unordered hash.  Then you can just iterate through the list in order and not pay attention to the keys ( command, command1, command2 are superfluous )

Comment: I would suggest not doing it at all. If you are going to let your Python script execute arbitrary shell commands, just replace `test2.json` with a shell script and have Python execute it directly.

Comment: @Chepner:  You could also accomplish the same result with a short shell script an no python code at all.

Comment: Yes, but I can picture a reason where the shell script is just a small part of what the Python script is doing. I see no reason to package individual lines of a shell script into a JSON file, only to be unpackaged again for execution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the structure and code you are looking for:

```
$ python -m json.tool test2.json
[
    "mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data2/opt/ODS",
    "mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data4/opt/ODS",
    "mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data5/opt/ODS"
]
```

Python:

```
$ cat parse.py 
import json
import sys
import subprocess
from pprint import pprint

jdata = open(sys.argv[1])

data = json.load(jdata)

print "start"
print(data)
for command in data:
  subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
print "end"
jdata.close()
```

Output:

```
$ python parse.py test2.json
start
[u'mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data2/opt/ODS', u'mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data4/opt/ODS', u'mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/data5/opt/ODS']
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example it would be better, to use [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

But if you REALLY need `subprocess` module - i suggest you to exec command with single subprocess instance. For example:

```
subprocess.call('; '.join(data.values()), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Mark's answer, but keeping your original structure:

```
$ cat parse.py
import json
import sys
import 
from pprint import pprint

jdata = open(sys.argv[1])

data = json.load(jdata)

print "start"
print(data)
for command in data.values():                
  subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
print "end"
jdata.close()
```

Comment: Why do you iterate over keys and values if you need just values ? Dictionaries have `.values()` method for that

Comment: Is the order of value retrieval from the dictionary guaranteed?  I think that the commands may not be executed in the order they were intended in the code above.

Comment: As long as the dict is not modified, yes. If there is still concern about order use `.iteritems()`. [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).